# Pyspark explode list creating column with index in list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have a question regarding pyspark. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---+------------+
| id|        list|
+---+------------+
|  2|[3, 5, 4, 2]|
+---+------------+
|  3|[4, 5, 3, 2]|
+---+------------+
```

And I would like to explode `lists` it into multiple rows and keeping information about which position did each element of the list had in a separate column. The result should look like this:

```
+---+------------+------------+
| id|    listitem|        rank|
+---+------------+------------+
|  2|           3|           1|
+---+------------+------------+
|  2|           5|           2|
+---+------------+------------+
|  2|           4|           3|
+---+------------+------------+
|  2|           2|           4|
+---+------------+------------+
|  3|           4|           1|
+---+------------+------------+
|  3|           5|           2|
+---+------------+------------+
|  3|           3|           3|
+---+------------+------------+
|  3|           2|           4|
+---+------------+------------+
```

The rank column has the index+1 of the position each element had in the list. Any suggestions on the most optimal code to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [posexplode()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#posexplode) or [posexplode_outer()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#posexplode_outer) function to get desired result.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2, [3, 5, 4, 2]), (3, [4, 5, 3, 2])], ["id", "list"])

df.select('id',posexplode_outer('list').alias('rank', 'listitem')) \
.withColumn('rank', col('rank') + 1).show()

+---+----+--------+
| id|rank|listitem|
+---+----+--------+
|  2|   1|       3|
|  2|   2|       5|
|  2|   3|       4|
|  2|   4|       2|
|  3|   1|       4|
|  3|   2|       5|
|  3|   3|       3|
|  3|   4|       2|
+---+----+--------+
```